# Could not lookup required component: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: maven, tycho

I started testing a Maven plug-in via the `maven-invoker-plugin`, and am stuck with a weird exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal my.company:plugin:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT:goal on project org.acme.simple: Could not lookup required component: java.util.NoSuchElementException 
[ERROR] role: my.company.plugin.SomeClass
```

I added the `maven-invoker-plugin` like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <pomIncludes>
                    <pomInclude>simple/pom.xml</pomInclude>
                </pomIncludes>
                <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/it</cloneProjectsTo>
                <settingsFile>src/it/settings.xml</settingsFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install</goal>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I -erm- borrowed the *settings.xml* from [this Maven plug-in](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-source-plugin/src/it/settings.xml). And what fails in the *pom.xml* to be tested is this call:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>my.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
            <version>@project.version@</version>
        </plugin>
```

After some more digging around, I figure that Tycho is at least part of the problem:

```
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.22.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If I remove `@project.version@` it works, but it's evidently not the current version of the plug-in that is tested. So I guess I have to leave it in. I tried adding `maven-compat` ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779351/component-lookup-exception-with-org-apache-maven-repository-repositorysystem-in)), but it didn't do anything.

The same exception is displayed when I don't add the plug-in in the *pom.xml*, but call it via:

```
invoker.goals=${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:${project.version}:goal
```

Any advice how to handle that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently this plug-in got lost somehow, adding it again made the exception go away:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-component-metadata</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate-metadata</goal>
                        <goal>generate-test-metadata</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```